# Database design for different prices based on the weight of the same product

Tags: sql, database, database-design, phpmyadmin

Each product in my database can have different prices based on the weight of the product. I'd also like to be able to set the available weight and price for said weight for each product. What would be the best way to do this?

EDIT:

Basically I have Product x and the customer can select 0.5kg, 1kg, 2.5kg etc but not all my products will have the same weights or, obviously, the same price for a  certain weight so I need to be able to save both the weights and the prices for the specific weight for each product.

For example :

Product 1 with weights 0.5kg - $60, 1kg -$105, 2kg - $198

Product 2 with weights: 0,1kg - $18, 0,250 kg - $30

etc

Comment: It sounds like you have a one-to-many relationship between product and price. Therefore, you should have a product table linked in a foreign-key relationship with a price table. The key in the price table needs to reflect the weight range, somehow. That said, you need to boil your question down to a more answerable question.

Comment: Basically I have Product x and the customer can select 0.5kg, 1kg, 2.5kg etc but not all my products will have the same weights or, obviously, the same price for a certain weight so I need to be able to save both the weights and the prices for the specific weight for each product.

For example :

Product 1 with weights 0.5kg - $60, 1kg -$105, 2kg - $198

Product 2 with weights: 0,1kg - $18, 0,250 kg - $30

etc

Answer (score 0):

You should have the price for a unit weight of the product, store this along with other details of the product, lets say you store this in a table called the product table.

Create a function which takes the productid (or whatever is your key to identify a product) and weight as an argument and returns the price of the product using the price of the unit weight of the product.

EDIT

Getting more details of your question you need to create 2 tables, one for product another which would contain the productid as a foreign key and would be mapped to the different weights and prices of the product.